# How to return a NSMutableArray from a method

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I have a method in a NSObject Class that I am executing from another ViewController Class, I would like to reutrn a NSMutableArray however I am not sure how to pass that into a variable in the ViewController class.

Updated Code:

NSObject Class is called Axis

Axis.h
// declare my method here with return type of NSMutableArray

```
- (NSMutableArray *)assignAxes:(NSArray*)axesData;
```

Axis.m

```
- (NSMutableArray *)assignAxes:(NSArray*)axesData {
//..

//pass some NSDictionaries into a MutableArray called myMutableArray

return myMutableArray;
}
```

Now I have a View Controller called FinalViewViewController and I want to call assignAxes method from this viewController, and I would like to put the returning myMutableArray into a mutableArray variable in FinalViewViewController but am not sure how... I only know how to call the method not pass the returning value into a variable to be used.

FinalViewViewController.m

```
Axis *axis = [[Axis alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *tempGetSeriesObjArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // create holder variable for returning mutableArray
    tempGetSeriesObjArray = [axis assignAxes:series]; // gives an error
```

This is the error I am getting from that last line of code

```
Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *__strong' from 'Axis *'
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: which error? maybe you didn't init the list?

Comment: **Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSMutableArray *__strong' from 'NSObjectClass *' **

Comment: Maybe if you want to pass an NSMutableArray you should pass an NSMutableArray.

Comment: (And what the heck is an NSObjectClass?)

Comment: Note that you don't pass anything into a class, you pass stuff to an *instance* of a class.  And the two most popular ways to do that are to make the thing being passed a parameter on `init`, or pass the value via a property.

Comment: how did you declare your NSMutableArray? please show us some code..

Comment: Note that you should **never** name one of your classes "NS...".  That prefix is reserved for Apple.  Also avoid "UI", "CF", et al.

Answer (score 1):

In your NSObject Class, first go in your .h file and make the declaration of the array and set the property

```
@interface YourNSObjectClass : NSObject {
    NSMutableArray *_myArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *_myArray;

- (NSMutableArray *) getMyArray; // declare method

@end
```

So now, you have to sync your variable and initialize it in the initMethod - if you have a custom init-method you have to declare it too and make it inside of there.

```
@synthesize _myArray;

- (id) init {
     if(self = [super init]) {
           _myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
     }
     return self;
}
```

And the getter-method should work too

```
- (NSMutableArray *) getMyArray {
    return _myArray;
}
```

Comment: yup this is what I have done this bit I am not too sure on what to do is how to pass that returning MutableArray into a MutableArray in the Viewcontroller I call it from.. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: a little bit more clean code would be great.. what's this NSObjectClass?

Comment: @HurkNburkS did you implemented your variable like in my answer?

Comment: Sorry just been updating the question. It shows you I have implemented everything.

Comment: @HurkNburkS you can upload your .h & .m file to some file server & I will try it in my xcode by myself to solve it..